# μ and σ calculations for a random variable with a normal distribution

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calculating mu and sigma (μ and σ) of a normal random variable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/78854/calculating-mu-and-sigma-and-of-a-normal-random-variable)

If I have a random variable X with parameters **μ** and **σ** unknown. It is known that $P (X \ge 75) = 0.7764$ and $P (X \ge 83) =  0.7291$ . With this information Is it possible to determine the **μ** and **σ** values ​​for $X$?

Comment: Duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/78854

Comment: looks like homework.

Comment: If you pay attention before you say the question is "duplicate", you would notice that in the previous question the probabilities were reversed and it was therefore impossible to calculate =)

Answer (score 2):

The title says that $X$ has normal distribution, but the text does not.  If we do not know the *distribution* of $X$, we cannot find the mean $\mu$ and the standard deviation $\sigma$ from the given data.  If we know that $X$ has normal distribution, we can. So from now on we assume that $X$ has normal distribution.

Recall that if $X$ has normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$, then $\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}$ has standard normal distribution. Thus 
$$P(X \le \mu +a\sigma)=P\left(\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}\le a\right) =P(Z\le a),\qquad\qquad(\ast)$$
where $Z$ has standard normal distribution.

For example, let $a=-1.5$.  Informally, if $X \le \mu-1.5\sigma$, we say that $X$ is at least $1.5$ standard deviation units *down* from the mean. So by $(\ast)$, we see that the probability that $X$ is at least $1.5$ standard deviation units down from the mean is $P(Z \le -1.5)$.  Similar considerations apply to $P(X \ge \mu-1.5\sigma)$.  The probability that $X$ is no more than $1.5$ standard deviation units down from the mean is $P(Z \ge -1.5)$. By the way, this is about  $0.9332$.

Finally, we look at the particular question. First, a quick look at the geometry.  We have $P(X \ge 75)=0.7764$.  Since the normal is symmetric, we can see that $75$ is *below* the mean. Similarly, $83$ is below the mean. Since $0.7764$ is less than $0.9332$, we can see that $75$ is less than $1.5$ standard deviation units below the mean. Now it is time to calculate.

If you look in a [table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_normal_table) of the standard normal distribution, you will find that $0.7764$ is (approximately) the probability that a standard normal $Z$ is $\le 0.76$, and $0.7291$ is the probability that a standard normal is $\le 0.61$.  The same sort of information is also available through various programs, such as spreadsheets, statistics packages, and general purpose mathematics packages such as *Maple* or *WolframAlpha*.

By symmetry, this means that $P(Z \ge -0.76)=0.7764$, and $P(Z \ge -0.61)=0.7291$.

But our normal $X$ has probability $0.7764$ of being $\ge 75$.  That means that $75$ is $0.76$ standard deviation units *down* from the mean.  In symbols,
$$\mu-0.76\sigma=75.$$
Similarly, we obtain
$$\mu-0.61\sigma=83.$$
Now we have two linear equations in two unknowns, and we can readily solve them for $\mu$ and $\sigma$.  A natural start is to observe that $(\mu-0.61\sigma)-(\mu-0.76\sigma)=83-75$, so $\sigma=8/(0.15)$. Note that our calculation has adequate accuracy, but is not exact, since the table entries are not exact.